# Configuring Multiple Compiler Plugins in a Single Project

Tags: neovim, makeprg, errorformat

Vim has compiler plugin feature which enables the user to write a compiler configuration, and then running `:make` will trigger the command, and `errorformat` will parse the output and will print any error in the quickfix. [Vim already comes with many compilers configured out of the box](https://github.com/vim/vim/tree/master/runtime/compiler). However, at any point, only one compiler is configured, and it is usually the compiler of the language that I work on.

In my case, I work with an environment that has multiple tools that could indicate issues/errors in the code. Consider java for example, I might run the compiler to compile the code, JUnit to run the tests, checkstyle, to check for any style issues, FindBug to find potential bugs, Fortify, to find security issues.

Suppose that I can find a compiler plugin for all of these tools, how can I use all of them together (maybe something like `make build`, `make test`, `make checkstyle`, `make findbug`, where each one of these commands uses a different plugin, thus different `errorformat`)?

Btw, I use neovim if that makes any difference.

Comment: You may be interested in [`vim-makery`](https://github.com/igemnace/vim-makery).

Comment: @user938271 that should be an answer